# Compare two text file using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare two files, and to extract lines in the first file that correspond to the second file for the first column. For example:

File 1:

```
VarID GeneID TaxName PfamName
3810359 1327    Isochrysidaceae Methyltransf_21&Methyltransf_22
6557609 5442    Peridiniales    NULL
4723299 7370    Prorocentrum    PEPCK_ATP
3019317 10454   Dinophyceae     NULL
2821675 10965   Bacillariophyta PK;PK_C
5559318 12824   Dinophyceae     Cyt-b5&FA_desaturase
```

File 2:

```
VarID
3810359
6557609
4723299
5893435
4852156
```

For the output I want this file :

```
VarID GeneID TaxName PfamName
3810359 1327    Isochrysidaceae Methyltransf_21&Methyltransf_22
6557609 5442    Peridiniales    NULL
4723299 7370    Prorocentrum    PEPCK_ATP
```

I tried this code :

```
f1 = sys.argv[1]
f2 = sys.argv[2]

file1_rows = []
with open(f1, 'r') as file1:
    for row in file1:
        file1_rows.append(row.split())

# Read data from the second file
file2_rows = []
with open(f2, 'r') as file2:    
    for row in file2:
        file2_rows.append(row.split())

# Compare data and compute results
results = []
for row in file2_rows:
    if row[:1] in file1_rows:
        results.append(row[:4])
    else:
        results.append(row[:4])

# Print the results
for row in results:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

Can you please help me ??? Thank you !!

Comment: Please supply output of your code.

Comment: Load the id of the second file, read the first line by line, if you find the id of the line on the loaded list print it else continue

Comment: replace the line: `if row[:1] in file1_rows:` with `if row[0] in file1_rows:`. also delete the else

Comment: @galfisher The output of my code is the entire first column of my first file

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
if row[:1] in file1_rows:
```

`row[:1]` returns a list with 1 field (the first column in the row). instead, search for that row directly.

this is the new code:

```
if row[0] in file1_rows:
```

also, remove the else that is associated to this if (I guess this is mistakly added duo to debugging)

There are few other better practices you can do,
I wrote them all here:

```
f1 = sys.argv[1]
f2 = sys.argv[2]

with open(f1, 'r') as file1:
    file1_rows = file1.read().splitlines()

# Read data from the second file
with open(f2, 'r') as file2:    
    file2_rows = file2.read().splitlines()

# Compare data and compute results
results = []
for row2 in file2_rows:
    for row in file1_rows:
        if row2 in row:
            results.append(row)
            break

print('\n'.join(results))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried like you said, but it prints me nothing

Comment: @Erika, I've updated my post, see if it what you meant